# input line height chrome/opera/ie

Tags: css, google-chrome, height, line, opera

Why google chrome is adding blank space between input fields? How can I get rid off the blank space?

http://s1.postimage.org/6djnd25wt/asddsadsdas.jpg

```
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100px;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the default `margin`. Replace your `margin-right` with:

```
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
```

That sets them all to `0`, and `margin-right` to `10px` as you had it.